# How to create CMYK color seperation combinations using GhostScript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, cmyk

I created color separations using

gs -sDEVICE=tiffsep -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -r600x600 -sOutputFile=p%08d.tif input.pdf

The outputs are all greyscale separations as documented.

Questions
1. How do I combine just the CYAN and MAGENTA separations (or any combination of colors) to make a PDF file?
2. How do I make sure the output PDF from the combo is in color and not greyscale?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Imagemagick's `convert` to combine CMYK separations; references:

- http://www.productionmonkeys.net/guides/ghostscript/examples
- [CMYK colors inverted with draw or annotate - ImageMagick forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=16534)
- [Combine 4 grayscale images into a final CMYK image - ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=31583)

Example: first, create RGB pdf with Latex (from https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19210/linux-gui-for-quick-browsing-of-cmyk-separations-of-multi-page-pdf); use this as `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=none,draw=black,line width=2pt] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (4cm,5cm);
\draw[fill=red] (1cm,1cm) circle (1cm) ;
\draw[fill=blue] (2cm,2.5cm) circle (1cm) ;
\draw[fill=green] (3cm,4cm) circle (1cm) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

... then build the PDF with:

```
pdflatex test.tex
```

Split RGB pdf into CMYK separations as tiff images using Ghostscript (see original softwarerecs thread for images), which will be called:

```
gs -sDEVICE=tiffsep -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -r150x150 -sOutputFile=test%04d.tif test.pdf
```

Merge/combine CMYK separations into a CMYK color tiff using Imagemagick:

```
convert \
test0001\(Cyan\).tif \
test0001\(Magenta\).tif \
test0001\(Yellow\).tif \
test0001\(Black\).tif \
-set colorspace CMYK -negate -combine combined.tif
```

... and here is how the final `combined.tif` looks like (I had to do `convert combined.tif combined.png` to upload it here, else `.tif` alone is not accepted):

[image: combined.png]

For comparison, here is a png derived from the original PDF (`convert -density 150 -flatten test.pdf test.png`):

[image: test.png]

Notice how the colors are slightly different, which is expected due to the colorspace roundtrip. Also, note that for more correct colors, you'll probably have to use ICC profiles during conversion...

Finally, you should find a way to convert/import the final CMYK color TIFF into a PDF... (probably either ghostscript or imagemagick could do that, but I haven't tried it..)

---

For just cyan and magenta - use a white image with the same size as the channel TIF separations, to insert it in place of the missing separations:

```
convert -size 240x299 xc:white white.png
```

... and then do the merge again:

```
convert \
test0001\(Cyan\).tif \
test0001\(Magenta\).tif \
white.png \
white.png \
-set colorspace CMYK -negate -combine combinedCM.tif
```

Here is the output (after `convert combinedCM.tif combinedCM.png`):

[image: combinedCM]

Answer (score 1):

Open the separations in an image editor which supports CMYK channels (eg Photoshop), combine the channels as required, save as PDF (or PostScript and use GS to convert to PDF).

Comment: I am looking for a way to do it programatically with ghostscript itself

Comment: Ghostscript can't do that. For starters it can't read TIFF files as input. There are ways around that, you can write a PostScript program to read TIFF files for instance. To colour the images (one per separation) you would want to construct an Indexed colour space which maps each 8-bit component to a 32-bit CMYK where only one channel has colour. The real trouble comes when you overlay the images, PostScript has an opaque imaging model so the last image drawn will obscure all the ones under it. It should be possible to use overprint for that. Big job to get this right.

Comment: Thanks for the comments KenS. Is there another programmatic way of doing this besides Ghostscript? ImageMagick or GIMP?

Comment: Not that I can think of offhand. If you want to view the result of combining channels, you could just create a PDF file and use Adobe Acrobat (professional), the print production tool has an ink manager that allows you to turn individual separations on and off and view the results. Its not completely obvious what you want to achieve.....

Comment: It's possible to do from command line with ImageMagick/`convert`, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935837/how-to-create-cmyk-color-seperation-combinations-using-ghostscript/42975414#42975414)